# Passing a Java Map to a C# program through a web service

Tags: c#, java, web-services

In a project I am working on I am trying to retrieve a Java map of images from a web service call.  The calling program is written in C# and is able to call other web service functions (in both C# or Java).  The issue is trying to access the data from the Java Map.  I was going to pass the Map data into a C# Dictionary, but the map is always null.  I have verified on the Java side that data is being returned, but the C# function shows my variable as null.

I was hoping somebody would have an idea as to why this is happening.  I'll post my simple code call to the Java web service below.  WebReference is a reference to the Java web service.

```
WebReference.ApplicationName testWeb = new WebReference.ApplicationName();
WebReference.Map testMap = new WebReference.Map();
testMap = testWeb.getMapImages();
```

EDIT) I'm not sure if it is pertinent or not, but the client code for the java web function handling was auto-generated through Visual Studio. The Map type was the best suggested return type for the Java function converter.

Comment: It looks like we'll need more information. Did you try looking at the data returned by the web service, to make sure the map is there? You should be able to use a web browser (or something like wget) to grab the reply page and have a look.

Comment: Yeah, a map with three images is being returned from the Java web function.  I assume the issue has to do with C# not having a Map data structure, but obviously I'm not sure.

Comment: well C#'s equivalent to Map is called Dictionary; they're close enough that you should be able to write Java code that serializes a Map and C# code that deserializes that back into a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to Serialize the map into something (json, xml,...) and then deserialize it in c# again into a Dictionary.

To serialize in java to json i can recommend [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).